# I want to print invoice on click using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new to the react , so for my project I wanted to print invoice by clicking on a button and my approach is as follows

The below code is for get print screen using iframe

```
 openFrame (print_c) 
{

        var pri = document.getElementById("ifmcontentstoprint").contentWindow;
        pri.document.open();
        pri.document.write(print_c.innerHTML);
        pri.document.close();
        pri.focus();
        pri.print();
}
```

The below code is within render() function

```
    var print_content= 
            <div><table cellPadding={0} cellSpacing={0} className="t0">
              <tbody><tr>..............</tr></tbody></table></div>;
<iframe id="ifmcontentstoprint" style={{height: 0, width: 0, position: 'absolute'}} />
    <button id={"invoice"+count} value={order.orderId} className="btn btn-info" style={{ color: "black", marginTop: "1%", marginBottom: "1%", marginLeft: "1%", marginRight: "1%", textAlign: "right"}} onClick={this.openFrame.bind(print_content)}>Generate Invoice</button>
```

Result is coming as undefined in the print screen

Comment: you dont have to getElementById in react

Comment: `print_content` isn't an HTMLElement, it has no `.innerHTML`. Assign an `id` to its `<div>` and use that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess,you should post the complete js file and the html file to give a clearer understanding of the issue. Below solution is based on my understanding from the code you have posed above.

The onClick handler is bound using the bind method. The bind method accepts the execution reference as the first argument. So you need to pass null or 'this' as the first argument and print_content as the second argument like so.

```
<button id={"invoice"+count} value={order.orderId} className="btn btn-info" style={{ color: "black", marginTop: "1%", marginBottom: "1%", marginLeft: "1%", marginRight: "1%", textAlign: "right"}} onClick={this.openFrame.bind(null, print_content)}>Generate Invoice</button>
```

**PS:** The execution reference is the object to which the 'this' keyword points to inside the function. As you have not used the 'this' keyword you can pass it as null.